# jQuery UI autocomplete wont display returned json (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, json, user-interface, autocomplete

The jQuery:

```
$("[type=text]").autocomplete({
source: "json.php",
minLength: 0
}).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
```

Works fine if I change the source: to a JS array.  I know that the php is working because I can see it in the console, but here is the sample php anyways:

```
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

So the dropdown just isn't displaying.  Feeling pretty stupid right about now.

Comment: The JSON from your PHP is being encoded to a object, not an array.  I'm not intimately familiar with jQuery.autocomplete, but is it expecting an array instead?

{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

vs

['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: Even when i try to return: `echo "['opt1','opt2','opt3','opt4']";` from the php page, it doesn't do anything.  I've also tried adding dataType: "json", to the options and nothing.

Comment: the problem is that you need 'label' or 'value' property in your json object to make the render automatically otherwise you need a custom select function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your json.php file, be sure to set the content encoding to be json via the header() function before your echo.  This way jQuery should see the array as proper json.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: I added it, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html

Check this get from demos site.

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't think so, I'm getting the response text in the console.

Comment: Yes, but you don't execute this code in your console ?  What is the site structure ? /subpage/my_form.php and /subpage/json.php, can you get the json.php like that ? Check your javascript error in your browser

Comment: Was talking about the browser's console window (actually firebug). Anyways json.php is in the same dir and I tried what you had suggested above - still nothing.  I see responsetext but nothing happens on the page.

Comment: yeah, i saw that but I have no idea what that back end looks like, I figured I'll need to parse the json some how, I just have no clue.

Comment: @jreed121 This is the backend  at  http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON :{"totalResultsCount":0,"geonames":[]}

Comment: You don't use the same syntaxe in your example as my link, to use autocomplete with ajax.

Comment: {"totalResultsCount":7796,"geonames":[{"adminCode3":"751","alternateNames":[{"name":"Parys","lang":"af"},{"name":"Paris","lang":"als"},{"name":"ፓሪስ","lang":"am"},{"name":"París","lang":"an"},{"name":"باريس","lang":"ar"},{"name":"ܦܪܝܣ","lang":"arc"},{"name":"París","lang":"ast"},{"name":"Парыж","lang":"be"},{"name":"Париж","lang":"bg"}, ...

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago I was also having problems with a JSON-populated Autocomplete.

My problem was that I wasn't setting the content-type, as Wally said above:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

I also wrapped my jQuery autocomplete call inside a getJSON, then used the data from that function to populate the autocomplete field.  My gut tells me that the extra getJSON shouldn't be necessary, but like you, I was having problems referencing my PHP file as the source.

```
$.getJSON("json.php", function(data) {
    $("[type=text]").autocomplete({
        dataType: "json",
        source: data,
        minLength: 1,
    }); 
});
```

Since I'm using an old PHP version, I hand-made my JSON.  I included "label" and "value" fields because I'm fairly certain they're necessary for the autocomplete to work.

```
$jsonList = "[{"label" : "Item 1", "value" : "1"}, {"label" : "Item 2", "value" : "2"}]";
return $jsonList;
```